# Unable to Create Multiple Subject Area Analysis in OBIEE 12c with a Non-Conformed Dimension

Tags: obiee

I am using OBIEE 12c 12.2.1.3. Trying to create an analysis from two Subject Areas with a non-conformed dimension

I have checked the checkbox "DIMENSIONALITY: Show Total value for all measures on unrelated dimensions" feature in Advanced Tab but getting SUM(DEMAND_F.QUANTITY) measure column as NULL

## Background

I have two facts and two dimensions

## Facts

1. DEMAND_F
2. ISSUANCE_F

## Dimensions

1. DEMAND_INFO_D (Conformed with both DEMAND_F and ISSUANCE_F)
2. ISSUANCE_INFO_D (Conformed with ISSUANCE_F only)

Analysis has columns

## ISSUANCE Subject Area

[ISSUANCE_INFO_D.IV_NUMBER], [SUM(ISSUANCE_F.IV_QUANTITY]]

## DEMAND Subject Area

[DEMAND_INFO_D.DEMAND_NO],[SUM(DEMAND_F.QUANTITY)],

Note: No Level based aggregation defined nor any level based hierarchy.

Expecting: Both measures should show values. I have seen some videos on the DIMENSIONALITY checkbox feature but not able to get the desired results.

Comment: Wait, you have no dimensional hierarchies at all defined in the RPD?

Comment: No dimensional hierarchies defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using OBI without dimensional hierarchies is the same thing as buying a Ferrari and then pushing it through the streets by hand and complaining that the car isn't working.

No dimensional hierarhcies means the tool has no idea how to navigate and aggregate between facts. It will simoly not work because it is a prerequisite!

It's an analytical tool. Use it correctly. Otherwise you may as well use a SQL query and Excel.

No, just setting the LTS content levels is not enough. The MEASURES must also comprehend what level they are on!

Comment: I created dimensional hierarchies and it works fine for the mentioned case. I added another process say "Shipment" after "Issuance". Shipment_F has no direct relationship with Demand_Info_D neither do Demand_F has with Shipment_Info_D. I set the granularity of Shipment_Info_D on Demand_F to Total and also the Demand_Info_D on Shipment_F to Total. The results are fine at Total level but no results at detail level of Demand Info for Shipment Info. Need to show Demand No, Issue No and respective Shipment No.

Comment: (To be read in continuity with previous comment) Demand_Info_D has relationship with Issuance_F and Issuance_Info_D has a relationship with Shipment_F. Need to show Demand No, Issue No and respective Shipment No. "DIMENSIONALITY: Show Total value for all measures on unrelated dimensions" also checked.